# How to test Java getter methods

Tags: java, junit, setter, getter

I have a class that will have these methods. In future there will be a method that sets email and password variables. But these variables would never be able for setup from outside of the class. How to test these methods?

```
public class Auth {
    private String email;
    private String password;

    public String getEmail(){
        return this.email;
    }

    public String getPassword(){
        return this.password;
    }
}
```

Comment: *Something* must set those fields to values, otherwise they are completely useless and should be removed. Are you asking how you would achieve TDD and have tests of non completed components?

Comment: Generally I would not describe a `get` as a unit of work. First, `set` and then `get` - that's a minimal UOW. I probably wouldn't test it, because I think it's safe to say that `A = A`.

Comment: The only way to set the fields is via reflection. So if you really want to test these dummy getters (I wouldn't), use reflection to set the fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't test getters, but some sensible units / use cases. Something must be creating these objects, and it is a part of this unit.

For example:

```
@Test
public void shouldCreateAuthFromColonSeparated() {
    Auth auth = authFactory.create("johnny@example.com:secret");
    assertThat(auth.getEmail(), is("johnny@example.com"));
    assertThat(auth.getPassword(), is("secret"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Testing getters and setters offers no markable benefits and can even be harmful. The reason for that is that *pure* getters and setters offer no business functionality which could be tested. Instead, they are part of the object oriented design principle (information hiding).

Comment: But the full coverage requires testing them. I know it's nonsense, but when the company forbids ignoring packages..

Comment: Full coverage does not necessarily mean that every method is called explicitly by a test.

Comment: Sure. But if the pipeline requires that and the configuration is not in your hand and if changing code is the only way... another thing is, if the type of a field changes, and you are with annotations like `@Data`, you don't have to change the getter/setter; but, changes in code may be required; in this situation, tests can detect the change.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you need to setup JUnit using `setUp()` overridden method whether password will be set in your `Auth` class.

Next thing you need to do is to get the value of actual password from database/whereverStored and compare it with the `getPassword()` value.

For testing then you can call:

```
Auth authObj = ...; //your Auth object where password is set
assertTrue(dbPassword.equals(authObj.getPassword()), true);
```